# Any way to get variables keys from jinja2 template string?

Tags: python, jinja2

Here is the code snippet I have initialized jinja2 template

```
from jinja2 import Template

templ = Template("{{foo}} to {{bar}}")
```

And I am willing to extract the template string variable keys from the template obj as below.

```
templ.keys() == ["foo", "bar"]
```

Is there any API to make it work? I have searched for a long while but got nothing work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

using [`jinja2.meta`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/api/#the-meta-api) you could:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, meta

templ_str = "{{foo}} to {{bar}}"
env = Environment()
ast = env.parse(templ_str)
print(meta.find_undeclared_variables(ast))  # {'bar', 'foo'}
```

which returns the `set` of the undeclared variables.

---

you could also use the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#module-re)gex module to find the variable names in your template string:

```
from jinja2 import Template
import re

rgx = re.compile('{{(?P<name>[^{}]+)}}')
templ_str = "{{foo}} to {{bar}}"
templ = Template(templ_str)

variable_names = {match.group('name') for match in rgx.finditer(templ_str)}
print(variable_names)  # {'foo', 'bar'}
```

the regex (could probably be better...) matches `{{` followed by anything that is not a curly bracket until `}}` is encountered.

Comment: Any other builtin methods or API could do the job like your answer?

Comment: Cool, Awesome job. That is exactly what i want. Thanks a lot.