# Python - Jinja2 - Can i recover key-value pairs from a rendered template string?

Tags: python, string, parsing, templates, jinja2

I am looking for a way to reclaim key-value pairs from a rendered jinja2 Template. In the example code below you can see

I looked at the following post:
[Any way to get variables keys from jinja2 template string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48685227/any-way-to-get-variables-keys-from-jinja2-template-string) 
It can get me as far as reclaiming keys, but i want to parse the string for the values as well so i can do a reverse lookup. The functionality would be similar to the Lucidity package's parse method
http://lucidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/tutorial.html#patterns

Is this possible with jinja2?

many thanks!

```
import jinja2

class ExamplePathCreator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.env = jinja2.Environment()
        self.my_template = self.env.from_string("""/{{test1}}/{{test2}}""")

    def render_my_template(self,test1="hello",test2="world"):
         return self.my_template.render(test1=test1,test2=test2)

    def get_keys(self,string_to_split):
        # HACK ALERT!!!! Want to replace with a function to invert
        #render_my_template back to key/value pairs
        splits = [x for x in string_to_split.split("/") if x != ""]
        d = {}
        d["test1"]=splits[0]
        d["test2"]=splits[1]
        return d

epc = ExamplePathCreator()
example = epc.render_my_template()
print( example )
print( epc.get_keys(example) )

# /hello/world
# {'test1': 'hello', 'test2': 'world'}
```

Comment: It's difficult to understand the motivation for this question - if you are in charge of rendering the template, why not just collect the keys and values from the beginning of the process instead of the end? Your 'render_my_template' function has all the info you need. If you are not in charge of the template rendering process, and all you get is the string output, then your question is "how do I parse a string in this format?", rather than anything to do with Jinja.